# How to get unique records using must and mustn't in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data like this

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "listing",
        "_type": "list2",
        "_id": "AVWBcQZIkMcl9M_bslCx",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "zid": "106"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "listing",
        "_type": "list1",
        "_id": "AVWBb_NjkMcl9M_bslCn",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "zid": "100"
        }
      }
]
```

Now I need unique zid but that zid is not presents in _type equal to "blist".

Advance Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am trying but I am not able to get any solution.

Comment: You want aggregated result for the unique zid?

Comment: yes but its not present with  _type  blist. its like a black list so black list is is not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do combination of aggregation and distinct values. For example:

```
 GET /<name of your index>/_search/
 {

    "aggregations" : {
      "label_agg" : {
         "terms" : {
           "field" : "zid",
           "size" : 100
          }
       }
    },
   "distinct_terms": {
     "cardinality": {
       "field": "zid"
     }
   }
 }
```

In above command, the aggregation will results in a bucket with all the unique value and the distinct_terms will result in the total number of aggregation values. You can use this total count to implement a loop to get each unique value contained in the bucket of aggregation